# Tabulator not recognizing columns?

Tags: json, tabulator

I have the following JSON:

```
{"contents":
[
   {"mossadId":2,"empId":"999666333","id":12},
   {"mossadId":4,"empId":"999666333","id":13},
   {"mossadId":2,"empId":"301301301","id":14}
]
}
```

I have verified this by writing this result to the console.

I am then using the following code to try make a table out of it:

```
                var response = (data.contents);  // remove containing 'contents' envelope
                console.log(response);
            
                var table12 = new Tabulator("#mossadListing", {
                    layout:"fitColumns",
                    data: response,
                    columns:[
                        {title:"organization", field:"mossaId", sorter:"string", width:100,
                    ]
                });
```

But i land us with a table with one columns, which all fields are empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to specify columns then the `field` name has to match the object key. Your data has:

`"mossadId"`

and the field is named:

`"mossaId"`

note the missing 'd'.

You also have only one field/column defined. If you want to see the rest you need to add them to `columns`.